# MySQL issue with select query and 'order by' clause

Tags: mysql, mariadb

We're experiencing a strange problem with a `SELECT` query against a MySQL database (InnoDB).

The following query incorrectly returns 1 matching record:

```
select `ID` 
from `AccessTables` 
where `numTableID` = 14 
    AND `numUserCatID` IN (7,253) 
    AND (`numUpdateCat` = 2 OR `numUpdateItems` = 2) 
order by `ID` asc 
limit 1
```

whereas the following query correctly returns no matching records:

```
select `ID` 
from `AccessTables` 
where `numTableID` = 14 
    AND `numUserCatID` IN (7,253) 
    AND (`numUpdateCat` = 2 OR `numUpdateItems` = 2) 
limit 1
```

As you can see, the only difference between these queries is the 'order by' clause.

The `ID` column requested in the query is the autogenerated primary key column for the table.

The record returned in the 1st query is a record that would be found if there were no brackets around the 'or' clause. 
But there ARE brackets around that part of the query, so I don't understand why this record is returned here. And then only if there is an 'order by' clause in the query.

The MySQL version in use is: MySQL Server: 5.5.32-MariaDB-log

Can anyone here shed some light on this issue? Thanks in advance.

(EDIT: leaving out the brackets does return a row, but that's another row than the one returned by the 1st query)

```
 insert  into `AccessTables`(`ID`,`numUserCatID`,`numTableID`,`numUpdateCat`,`numPublishCat`,`numUpdateItems`,`dateInsert`,`dateUpdate`,`numInsertAuthorID`,`numUpdateAuthorID`,`numViewItems`) values (71,15,14,0,0,2,'2008-03-13 23:38:47','2013-04-04 09:34:36',0,513,2);
```

(EDIT nr. 2: no MariaDB, but .... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a922/8)

Edit  nr. 3, running these queries against the real MariaDB thing:

Query1:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT `ID` 
FROM `AccessTables` 
WHERE `numTableID` = 14 
    AND `numUserCatID` IN (7,253) 
    AND (`numUpdateCat` = 2 OR `numUpdateItems` = 2) 
ORDER BY `ID` ASC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Output:

```
"id"    "select_type"   "table" "type"  "possible_keys" "key"   "key_len"   "ref"   "rows"  "filtered"  "Extra"<br />
"1" "SIMPLE"    "AccessTables"  "range" "numUserCatID,numTableID,numUpdateCat,numUpdateItems"   "numTableID"    "8" \N  "136"   "11.03" "Using where"
```

Query2:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT `ID` 
FROM `AccessTables` 
WHERE `numTableID` = 14 
    AND `numUserCatID` IN (7,253) 
    AND (`numUpdateCat` = 2 OR `numUpdateItems` = 2) 
LIMIT 1;
```

Output:

```
"id"    "select_type"   "table" "type"  "possible_keys" "key"   "key_len"   "ref"   "rows"  "filtered"  "Extra"<br />
"1" "SIMPLE"    "AccessTables"  "range" "numUserCatID,numTableID,numUpdateCat,numUpdateItems"   "numUserCatID"  "8" \N  "20"    "75.00" "Using index condition; Using where"
```

Query3:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT `ID` 
FROM `AccessTables` 
WHERE `numTableID` = 14 
    AND (numUserCatID = 7 OR numUserCatID = 253) 
    AND (`numUpdateCat` = 2 OR `numUpdateItems` = 2) 
ORDER BY `ID` ASC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Output:

```
"id"    "select_type"   "table" "type"  "possible_keys" "key"   "key_len"   "ref"   "rows"  "filtered"  "Extra"<br />
"1" "SIMPLE"    "AccessTables"  "range" "numUserCatID,numTableID,numUpdateCat,numUpdateItems"   "numTableID"    "8" \N  "136"   "11.03" "Using where"
```

EDIT nr. 4:
Removing the 'limit 1' has the same result as removing the 'order by': no rows are found.

Query 4:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT `ID` 
FROM `AccessTables` 
WHERE `numTableID` = 14 
    AND `numUserCatID` IN (7,253) 
    AND (`numUpdateCat` = 2 OR `numUpdateItems` = 2) 
ORDER BY `ID` ASC;
```

Output:

```
"id"    "select_type"   "table" "type"  "possible_keys" "key"   "key_len"   "ref"   "rows"  "filtered"  "Extra"<br />
"1" "SIMPLE"    "AccessTables"  "range" "numUserCatID,numTableID,numUpdateCat,numUpdateItems"   "numUserCatID"  "8" \N  "20"    "75.00" "Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort"
```

So, the queries that return the correct result (0 records found) seem to work with the index on numUserCatID, whereas the queries that return the incorrect result (1 record found) seem to work with the index on numTableID.

Strange...!

EDIT nr. 5:
Ordering by another column, eg. dateInsert (which is a date/timestamp representing the moment the record was inserted into the table), also changes the query result.
Then there are again no records returned and the index used is the one on numUserCatID again.

We were using the 'order by `ID` asc' because we assumed that the ID's would always represent the order in which the records were inserted into the DB.
But dateInsert does essentially the same in our case.

Would there be performance penalties in a large database when using a regular key column for ordering instead of the primary key?

Comment: Is there any chance we can get a copy of the data for that row, or at least the columns related to the issue?

Comment: Are those two queries auto-generated (in some app) or you're running them in trusted environment (for example, with mysql-cli) and see that weird result?

Comment: This seems like a bug. Send a bug report to **[MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs/)**.

Comment: Can you show us the row returned? (I mean all the columns, not just the `ID`.

Comment: Which engine is the table using? Is `AccessTables` a base table or a view?

Comment: The row (and its column names) that is returned is this one:

insert into `AccessTables` (`ID`, `numUserCatID`, `numTableID`, `numUpdateCat`, `numPublishCat`, `numUpdateItems`, `dateInsert`, `dateUpdate`, `numInsertAuthorID`, `numUpdateAuthorID`, `numViewItems`) values('71','15','14','0','0','2','2008-03-13 23:38:47','2013-04-04 09:34:36','0','513','2');

(this has the form of a SQL statement as I don't know how to get this information here otherwise)

AccessTables is a base table, not a view.

Comment: You can run `SELECT * FROM AccessTables WHERE id = 71;`

Comment: So, it returns a row with `numUserCatID=15`, right?

Comment: Yes, it does. But I'm querying for a row where numUserCatID is 7 or 253. That's not 15.

Answer (score 2):

**If this really happens, it's a bug.** With "really" I mean that these are the exact queries that you are sending to the database server and the underlying tables have not been updated in the mean time.

A similar (but not identical) isssue is here: **[MDEV-2662](https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-2662)**

Please report the issue to the MariaDB team.

---

To solve the immediate problem, try rewritting the query, for example without the `IN`, replacing;

```
AND numUserCatID IN (7,253)
```

with:

```
AND (numUserCatID = 7 OR numUserCatID = 253)
```

and check if you get same erroneous results.

Comment: That rewrite of the query (thus losing the IN clause) seems to solve the issue.

Comment: I suggest you add in your question, the output of the `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` for all 3 versions of the query (the 2 in the question and the 3rd without IN.) If you can also setup a small script at [SQLFiddle.com](http://SQLFiddle.com) it would be even better (although the bug won't show there, no MariaDB, others could copy the scripts in their machine and reproduce the bug.)

Comment: Thank you. Please edit the question with this link and the EXPLAIN outputs from your machine.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with MarjaR on this, and after testing: this bug in MariaDB 5.5 is resolved in 5.5.37